# Cannot save product images in admin

Tags: magento2, product

When creating a new product in the Magento2 admin I get an error upon saving.

It says:

```
The file "/path/to/folder/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product/p/productimage.jpg" doesn't exist or not a file.
```

I can't create new products. Please help.

Comment: check permissions for pub/media. You should have permissions for save

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check permissions for pub/media. 
You should have permissions for save.

If you want to read about permissions more (you should. Everyone should:D)
visit Magento devdocs:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and figured out that it is a Magento bug.

There was already a image, but it was missing, since I setup a new magento installation without media and imported a database, and there was an image previously, but it can't load since the media folder is missing.

[image: I]

I deleted the image by clicking on the trash bin and uploaded a new one. But after saving it was gone.

## Solution 1

Don't delete missing image, just upload new one by clicking "Browse to find ..."

## Solution 2

```
Delete Missing image -> Save -> Upload new image -> Save
```